# Use row value from CTE in function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to use row values from CTE expressions to pass to a function.
Something like:

```
WITH
  start_number(x) as (VALUES(1)),
  end_number(y) as (VALUES(10)),
  z AS (SELECT * FROM generate_series(start_number.x, end_number.y))
SELECT z.*
```

What's the syntax?

Notes: start_number & end_number may be the result of a query, typically returning a single row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `from` clause so you can get `x` and `y`:

```
WITH start_number(x) as (
      VALUES (1)
     ),
     end_number(y) as (
      VALUES (10)
    ),
    z AS (
     SELECT gs.z
     FROM start_number CROSS JOIN
          end_number CROSS JOIN LATERAL
          generate_series(start_number.x, end_number.y) gs(z)
    )
SELECT z.*
FROM z;
```

Merely defining a CTE does not make it available to subsequent code and CTEs in the query.  You need to include the CTE in a `FROM` clause.

In addition, you should be in the habit of naming the columns in CTEs.  In your code `z` has a column with no name.

The above is one method.  You could also use subqueries as well:

```
WITH start_number(x) as (
      VALUES(1)
     ),
     end_number(y) as (
      VALUES(10)
    ),
    z AS (
     SELECT *
     FROM generate_series((SELECT x FROM start_number), (SELECT y FROM end_number))
    )
SELECT z.*
FROM z;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0c6cfcdf333cf2b7c03b723e25157edd) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the two CTEs in the FROM clause:

```
WITH start_number(x) as (
  VALUES(1)
), end_number(y) as (
  VALUES(10)
)
SELECT * 
FROM start_number, end_number, generate_series(start_number.x, end_number.y))
```

You can simplify that by using only a single CTE for the numbers:

```
WITH params(start_number, end_number) as (
  VALUES (1, 10)
)
SELECT * 
FROM params p, generate_series(p.start_number, p.end_number))
```